# Get current unix_timestamp in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

As the post [How to select current date in Hive SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905873/how-to-select-current-date-in-hive-sql), to get the current date in Hive, `unix_timestamp` can be used.

But I tried

```
select unix_timestamp();
```

and just,

```
unix_timestamp();
```

both give the error messages

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:23 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting FROM near ')' in from clause
FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'unix_timestamp' '(' ')'
```

respectively.

How can I use `unix_timestamp` properly in Hive?

## UPDATED!

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-178 has resolved this issue.

If you use 0.13 (released on 21 April 2014) or above, you can

```
-- unix_timestamp() is deprecated
select current_timestamp();
select 1+1;
```

without `from <table>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hive doesn't expose a [dual table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table), you may want to create a single lined table, and use that table for that kind of querys.

You'll then be able to execute queries like

```
select unix_timestamp() from hive_dual;
```

A workaround is to use any existing table, with a LIMIT 1 or a TABLESAMPLE clause, but, depending on the size of your table, it will be less efficient.

```
# any_existing_table contains 10 lines
# hive_dual contains 1 line

select unix_timestamp() from any_existing_table LIMIT 1; 
# Time taken: 17.492 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
select unix_timestamp() from any_existing_table TABLESAMPLE(1 ROWS);
# Time taken: 15.273 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

select unix_timestamp() from hive_dual ;
# Time taken: 16.144 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
select unix_timestamp() from hive_dual LIMIT 1; 
# Time taken: 14.086 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
select unix_timestamp() from hive_dual TABLESAMPLE(1 ROWS);
# Time taken: 16.148 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

**Update**

No need to pass any table name and limit statement. Hive does support `select unix_timestamp()` now.

More details :

[Does Hive have something equivalent to DUAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795668/does-hive-have-something-equivalent-to-dual)

[BLOG POST : dual table in hive](http://bigdatadw.blogspot.ca/2012/02/dual-table-in-hive.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get the date out of timestamp use to_date function.

Try the below

```
select to_date(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())) as time from table_name;
```

Comment: it shows date strings as the number of entries in `table_name`. Is it possible without a table?